# Как правильно создавать группу кнопок открывающих модальное окно на JS?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть **несколько кнопок**, которые, по идее, **открывают одно и тоже модальное окно**, но этот код этого делать не хочет. Только если в конец строки переменной "more" добавить "[num]", то сработает кнопка под номером "num".

Я в JS совсем новичок, я уверен, что решение моей проблемы максимально лёгкое, но я надеюсь на ваше понимание и помощь))

```js
let more = document.querySelectorAll('.more'),
    overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay'),
    close = document.querySelector('.popup-close');

  more.addEventListener('click', function () {
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
    this.classList.add('more-splash');
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  });

  close.addEventListener('click', function () {
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
    more.classList.remove('more-splash');
    document.body.style.overflow = '';
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию (подобную массиву), а не отдельный элемент

```
let more = document.querySelectorAll('.more'),
    overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay'),
    close = document.querySelector('.popup-close');

more.forEach(function(but){
    but.addEventListener('click', function () {
        overlay.style.display = 'block';
        this.classList.add('more-splash');
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    })
});
```

Comment: `more.forEach(function(el){ el.addEventListener(...`

Comment: @Igor Спасибо. Загнался.

Comment: @Igor Может подскажете, раньше вроде forEach не рекомендовалось непосредственно к HTMLCollection применять. Я и зарубил на носу, а сейчас гляжу работает, что-то изменилось?

Comment: Не помню как раньше, но сейчас пример с `forEach` прямо здесь - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll. Вы не путаете с `for (... in ...)`?

Comment: Нет, не путаю, но помню, что всегда использовали преобразование к массиву еще года 2 назад))) [...more].forEach

Comment: Хм, может быть имелись в виду live коллекции?

Comment: Нет, все нормально, все правильно. Я просмотрел еще раз. В NodeList, возвращаемый querySelectorAll добавили родной метод forEach относительно недавно и поддержка появилась у браузеров не сразу. IE до сих пор не поддерживает.